# How to get controls described in XAML file in a Xamarin Form project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I can't properly get the control described in XAML file. I gave button in XAML file a `ClassId` and tried to reach it in CS file using `FindByName`.

This is in a Xamarin Form project running in iOS Emulator.

In `MainPage.XAML` file,

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button Text="" />
    <Label ClassId="myLabel1"
       Text="Xamarin Form Demo" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <Button ClassId ="btnNum"
       Text="Image Control" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Image ClassId="myImg" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Label ClassId="myLabel2"
       Text="Number" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs file,

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int num = 0;
        ((Button)FindByName("btnNum")).Clicked += (o, e) ((Label)FindByName("myLabel2")).Text = (++num).ToString();
    }
```

When I run the app on iOS Emulator, I always get the following error in the longest line of code in `MainPage.xaml.cs` file,

> *********
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object
>
> *********

Thanks for the help, and it would be nice if I can get some further information about accessing control from a different content page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign your control a Name

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="" />
```

then in the code-behind refer to it by name - you should not need to declare it

```
MyButton.Text = "blah blah blah";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, although referring to the button using its name directly doesn't work for me, but "((Button)FindByName("btnNum")).Clicked" this works very well now! In the XAML file, the Name has to follow "x:", what is this "x:"? Do I need to use it for other properties? I didn't find the property "Name" in the Element description document from Microsoft.

Comment: the "x" prefix is a XAML namespace.  If this is not working then there is something wrong with your environment.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `x:Name` directive, which can be used in any control within Xamarin.Forms.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-name-directive):

> Uniquely identifies XAML-defined elements in a XAML namescope. XAML
>   namescopes and their uniqueness models can be applied to the
>   instantiated objects, when frameworks provide APIs or implement
>   behaviors that access the XAML-created object graph at run time.

Usage in XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="myLabel1"
       Text="Xamarin Form Demo" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

<Button 
       x:Name ="btnNum"
       Text="Image Control" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

In Page.xaml.cs

```
myLabel1.Text = "test";
btnNum.Clicked +=
```

Comment: @solidcomer don't forget to mark as correct and upvote :D